# Matlab imwrite() quality

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm very new to Matlab, though I know a few other programming languages, so please forgive me if this is something simple. I have not been able to find any answers to this, either on StackOverflow or elsewhere.

I produce a figure using the following code:

```
 figure(6),imageplot(P); drawnow;
```

Which looks like this: [image]

I then save this image to my computer using the following commands:

```
imwrite(P, 'images/plot.png');
```

And the resulting image is tiny, and missing some of the color information:

[image]

If, however, I utilize the save function in the open figure (image #1) and save it manually, I get exactly what I want, which is that exact image stored on my computer.

[image]

How would I program that? I assumed that imwrite() would just write the image directly, but apparently I'm doing something wrong. Any advice? Perhaps it has something to do with the imageplot command? I cannot seem to get that to work in imwrite.

Update: Based on the comments below, I have begun using "imresize" with the "nearest" option. This scales the image properly, but the resulting image is still curiously darker (and therefore has less information) than if I hit the "save" button in the figure.

Image saved from figure:

[image]

Image using "imresize" with "nearest" option:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you need for the "Save As..." functionality of figures is called "print". I often use

```
print(gcf, '-dpng', 'some_filename.png')
```

or

```
print(gcf, '-depsc', 'some_filename.eps','-r0')
```

to save a figure as it is shown on screen. The format png offers a small filesize and excellent quality, and it is understood by most image viewers and browsers. The eps format is a vector format, which I use for printig. The '-r0' option specifies "use the same size as given by the screen resolution" for the vector format properties.

Comment: How would you suggest I combine my code with the print() function? As stated in my question, I am able to view the image I want using imageplot(P). Using print(P, '-dpng','filename.png') yields an error: "Handle input must be scalar, vector, or cell-array of vectors."



I have also tried using print(imageplot(P),'-dpng','filename.png') in an attempt to print exactly what I display, but that yields the error "Too many output arguments".

Comment: You need to use print on a figure handle - after you've plotted your matrix P, `gcf` returns the current figure handle, as Martin J.H. uses. You could also use `f=figure; imageplot(P); print(f,...);`.

Comment: There we go. Perfection. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The MATLAB `imwrite` command saves exactly the number of pixels as specified in your image matrix. This is the actual result of your computation; the reason the output is "tiny" is because it is supposed to be. To make it larger, would be to simply scale/zoom it as required.

The save figure option however does something quite different: it rasterizes the the output you obtain in the figure window and gives you the option for saving it as an image. This is evident in the fact that when you do so, you obtain a white background in addition to your result which is really just the grey background you see before you save it; this can be adjusted by resizing the figure window before utilizing the save option.

If you're looking to simply make the output figure larger, I would recommend using something along the lines of the `imresize` command.

Say, if you want the default size to be twice the size of the real result, simply use:

```
imresize(P, 2.0);
```

For more options, try `help imresize`.

Comment: That does indeed resize the image, but it appears to use the previously rasterized version and just makes it larger. So, for instance, running imwrite(imresize(P, 2.0), filename);  simply stretches the image to twice the dimensions - it is larger, but extremely blurry and still missing some of the color information from the original figure.

Comment: Use the `'nearest'` option of `imresize` to stop the interpolation (and hence blurring) from happening.

Comment: Please see my update - using nearest works, but it's still not exactly what I want, because although the scaling works now, it is significantly darker.

Comment: @user774359: [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#f25-742371) seems simpler option here. It doesn't even require that you create a figure. You'll need to resize your 1-by-1 pixels to 72 dpi screen resolution, or whatever you want. I think the reason that the resultant image is darker, is due to the default 8-bit [`'bitdepth'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#bq36zrr-1) for grayscale PNGs. `print` outputs (truecolor) 24-bit (8 bits per channel) RGB PNGs regardless of what the input is. Check the docs for how to alter `imwrite`'s output.